# Does there exists a differentiable function $f$ s.t for each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f'(x)=[x]$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I am not sure about this question.
Suppose there's such a function then $f$ should be continuous, then we should have: 
$$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x [y] dy$$

For $x>1$:
$$f(x)-f(0)= \int_0^1 [y] dy + \int_1^x [y]dy$$
how to continue from here?
I thought to dissect the second integral to intervals from $[1,2], [2,3] , \ldots , [[x],x]$, and then if I am not mistaken it should be:
$$f(x)=f(0)+0 + 1+2+\ldots [x](x-[x])$$

But I don't think this function is continuous, so I guess the answer to the title question is no, am I right or wrong?

Comment: This cannot be true by Darboux's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)

Comment: Look up Darboux's Theorem which implies that an everywhere derivative can't have a jump discontinuity (I.e. Derivatives satisfy the intermediate value theorem even when they are discontinuous).

Comment: By $[x]$, do you mean $\lfloor x\rfloor$ (the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions))?

Comment: @robjohn , yes.

Comment: If you define $f$ by that  integral then $f$ _is_ continuous! (But  i's not true that $f'(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$.)

Comment: Notation: See \lfloor and \rfloor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an arguement that avoids Darboux Theorem for derivatives : conisder $\frac {f(x)-f(0)} {x-0}$ on $(0,\infty)$. By MVT and the hypothesis this must be an integer $n$. But if a continous function takes only integer values it must be a constant, so the integer $n$ does not depend on $x$. This gives $f(x)=f(0)+nx$ for all $x >0$. But this function obviously does not satisfy the hypothesis.

Thus Darboux Theorem is an overkill for this simple question.

Answer (score 1):

No, as you can see by Darboux's theorem. This is a good example to show that the primitive functions and integral functions are not always the same. Another example is the $x \mapsto \operatorname{sgn}(x)$: We have that
$$\int_0^x \operatorname{sgn}(t)\mathrm{d}t=|x|$$
But $\nexists f$ so that $f'=\operatorname{sgn}$.

Comment: See my comment to  the question. $[x]$ means floor, not absolute value.

Comment: @robjon I know. I just wanted to show that $\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ is another example.